# AWS Cognito and S3

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cognito

I am working on Android app in which users upload and download files from `Amazon S3`. I have developed authentication for my app. Currently, whenever user wants to upload few files, for every file user get `IdentityID` and `Token` by pinging my back end.

I have few questions

1. How do I know if the token is expired?
2. Does `AWS API` save token and Identity itself? If yes, how to retrieve them?
3. What might be the best way to make use of `IdentityId` and token for my project? Calling back-end for every file to get Token? Or calling for once when user wants to upload a bunch (selected) of files? Or saving token and reusing it if the token is not expired?

CODE:

Auth.java:

```
public class Auth extends AWSAbstractCognitoDeveloperIdentityProvider {



private Context ctx;
public Auth(String accountId, String identityPoolId, Regions region,Context ctx) {
    super(accountId, identityPoolId, region);
      this.ctx=ctx;

}

@Override
public String getProviderName() {
   return "cognito-identity.amazonaws.com";

}

@Override
public String refresh() {
    setToken(null);

    if (getProviderName() != null &&
            !this.loginsMap.isEmpty() &&
            this.loginsMap.containsKey(getProviderName())&& internetchek.connectGoogle()) {

        Log.d("Refreshing..","Loading..");
        Idtoken();

        update(identityId, token);

        return token;



    } else {

        this.getIdentityId();
        return null;
    }

}
@Override
public String getToken() {
    return token;
}

public void Idtoken(){



    String serverurl = constants.IP_ADDRESS_CREDENTIALS;
    try {
        save s = new save(this.ctx, constants.USER_DETAILS);
        String phonenumber = s.read(constants.PHONE_NUMBER);

        if (phonenumber != null) {


            URL url = new URL(serverurl);
            HttpURLConnection http = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            http.setRequestMethod("POST");
            http.setDoInput(true);
            http.setDoOutput(true);

            OutputStream OS = http.getOutputStream();
            BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(OS, "UTF-8"));
            String data = URLEncoder.encode("number", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(phonenumber, "UTF-8");
            bufferedWriter.write(data);
            bufferedWriter.flush();
            bufferedWriter.close();
            OS.close();
            InputStream IS = http.getInputStream();
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(IS, "iso-8859-1"));
            String line = "";
            String response="";

            while ((line= bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                response = response+line;

            }
            bufferedReader.close();
            IS.close();
            http.disconnect();

            response = response.replaceAll("\\s+", "");

            Log.d("RESPONCE", response);

            String[] splitter = response.split("==");
            if (splitter[0] != null) {

                if (splitter[1] != null) {

                    identityId = splitter[0];
                    token = splitter[1];

                }

            }
        }
            Log.d("IDENTITYID",identityId);
            Log.d("TOKEN",token);

        }catch(MalformedURLException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }catch(UnknownHostException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }catch(IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

}}
```

Uploadfile

```
private class Uploadfile extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void>{

    Context ctx;
    String remotepath;
    File file;
    ProgressBar progressBar;

    private Uploadfile(Context ctx,File file,String remotepath,ProgressBar progressBar){
        this.ctx =ctx;
        this.file=file;
        this.remotepath=remotepath;
        this.progressBar =progressBar;
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        if(!internetchek.isNetworkAvailable(this.ctx)||!internetchek.connectGoogle()){
            Log.d("NETWORK","TRUE");
        }else {
            Auth developerProvider = new Auth(
                    null,
                    "ap-northeast-1:a871fa5fxxxxxxxxxxxxx1437244",
                    Regions.AP_NORTHEAST_1, this.ctx);
            CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider credentialsProvider = new CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider(
                    this.ctx.getApplicationContext(),
                    developerProvider,
                    Regions.AP_NORTHEAST_1);


            HashMap<String, String> loginsMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
            loginsMap.put("cognito-identity.amazonaws.com", credentialsProvider.getToken());
            credentialsProvider.setLogins(loginsMap);
            credentialsProvider.refresh();

            ClientConfiguration configuration = new ClientConfiguration();
            configuration.setProtocol(Protocol.HTTP);
            configuration.setSocketTimeout(5 * 10000);
            configuration.setConnectionTimeout(5 * 10000);
            configuration.setMaxErrorRetry(3);
            configuration.setMaxConnections(100);

            if (sS3Client == null) {

                sS3Client = new AmazonS3Client(credentialsProvider, configuration);

            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
        super.onPostExecute(aVoid);

        if(sS3Client!=null){

            sTransferUtility = new TransferUtility(sS3Client, this.ctx);

            observer = sTransferUtility.upload(remotepath, file.getName(), file);
            transferObservers.add(observer);

            observer.setTransferListener(new UploadListener(this.progressBar,observer,file.getPath()));

        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. I can think of two methods offhand:

   a. A simple try/catch around code that uses the token. If it throws back an appropriate exception, get a new one and retry.

   b. With developer authenticated identities, you configure the valid length of the token. You could easily track that inside the app and act appropriately as it expires. This is the route I'd recommend.
2. I'm not sure what you mean by this. The SDK does store them after they're retrieved. You can get the id with getIdentityId() or getCachedIdentityId(), why do you need the token?
3. The ideal/recommended flow is you not having to do anything with them manually. Once the SDK has them, you should just be able to use the credentials provider to get credentials with which you can access S3. This would lmean saving the token and reusing it, but again, this should be no additional work on your part.

EDIT:

You should not be re-creating the credentials provider in a new thread every time. It'll lose state and you'll constantly have to contact your back end. It should be a singleton, as exemplified in the [blog post](http://mobile.awsblog.com/post/Tx3E3NJURV1LNV1/Integrating-Amazon-Cognito-using-developer-authenticated-identities-An-end-to-en) and the sample (linked on that blog post).

You should also be giving the provider the key of the provider you configured on the console, not cognito-identity.amazonaws.com.

The way you're setting the token looks off, too. The sample sets the logins like this:

```
CognitoSyncClientManager
            .addLogins(
                    ((DeveloperAuthenticationProvider) CognitoSyncClientManager.provider
                            .getIdentityProvider()).getProviderName(),
                    userName);
```

I'd recommend giving the sample another look, there appears to be a few differences in implementation.

Comment: "This would lmean saving the token and reusing it, but again, this should be no additional work on your part" does this mean API stores token and reuse it automatically?

Comment: The SDK should, not necessarily the API.

Comment: Looks like. I screwed up something in my code. I posting it here. Please look at the code

Comment: I am new to aws sdk usage. Very helpful if you say where i went wrong. And where should have to add code to retrieve existing token and IdentityID? Is this code proper way of usage?

Comment: 2 things stand out - you should use the provider name you configured on the console in getProviderName(), and (the crucial one) the CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider should absolutely be a singleton instead of created in a parallel thread each time. That's likely your key issue. Also, I think I just replied on the forums to your post there :p.

Comment: whenever I put my providername, getting error. have you seen logins? was that correct way?

Comment: I'd rather not do this in two places. Per both the docs and the example app, you should set it as your provider name configured in the console. Did you try the other suggestion I gave above, that I said I thought was the issue?

Comment: The sample shows the expected usage of the login (https://github.com/awslabs/aws-sdk-android-samples/blob/master/CognitoSyncDemo/src/com/amazonaws/cognito/sync/demo/DeveloperAuthenticationTask.java#L53)

Comment: I tried what you said. But it did not work. regarding the loginsmap, I read in an blog(I think author name is Bob) to put "cognito-identity.amazonaws.com" and token as value in logins map. That's why i put it there.

Comment: In any case, the credentials provider should absolutely be a singleton and not created in a new thread every time. It should be re-used. From https://mobile.awsblog.com/post/Tx2FL1QAPDE0UAH/Understanding-Amazon-Cognito-Authentication-Part-2-Developer-Authenticated-Ident, I see 'you can additionally supply a user identifier keyed by the developer provider name that you set when you created the identity pool. This should be a unique identifer for this user in your system.' from Bob in that blog post.

Comment: Added more detail to my answer with specifics.

Comment: Thank you very much. So the logins are additional rite? because I am calling getOpenIdTokenForDeveloperIdentity from my backend already with unique userID.

Comment: It's a mandatory step. From the blog post I linked: 'If the request is successful, then it adds your provider name and user identifier to the logins map. The developer user identifier can be an alphanumeric string that uniquely identifies a user in your backend. In the sample, we use username as a developer user identifier.'

Comment: Looks like, I am facing problem in proper understanding of how Cognito works. I have to read cognito blogs again and try. thank you very much

Comment: Sorry for the issues. That sample is probably a good place to start, it covers all of the issues from your initial questions. If you don't necessarily want to use your own back end, it might be significantly easier to try the new service Cognito User Pools. It does all of this for you.

Comment: I worked it out.  replaced getProvidername with my custom provider name in console it worked.But I have a question, my backend calls  getOpenIdTokenForDeveloperIdentity with unique username to get IdentityID and token, and those two will get passed to android app for using with credentialprovider. here credential provider logins should be with providername and username, obviously I have to put the same username as the username that I used from backend to get token and identityID. right?

Comment: in the logins map I used same username as I used in my backend  it worked. But it also worked with different username in logins map for same providername

Comment: Glad to hear it's up and running, I'll link this to the forum post for future reference for others. Yes, you should use the same username for both.